# How to return list of multiple addresses from latitude and longitude co-ordinates using Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, latitude-longitude

Hoping someone will have some idea about this – I’m sort of tearing my hair out!

We have a list of around 600 sites (column `A`), with corresponding lat and long co-ordinates (columns `C` and `D`), and we’re trying to work out a way that when we plug in co-ordinates of someone’s address (cells `F2` and `G2`), we can return a list of the 50 or so closest sites to that one.

The formula below will return the closest site to the address:

```
=LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,MMULT((C2:D7000-$F$2:$G$2)^2,{1;1})),A2:A585)
```

But I can’t figure out how to work the formula to then search for the next closest site after that one.

Does anyone have any ideas?

(Given the relatively small distances we’ll be working with, we probably don’t need to worry about accounting for circular distances – using `RADIANS` etc.)

Thanks so much in advance.

EDIT:

[image: Sample of data set]

Comment: Why not create an upper and lower lat & long and get the ones in between those values? Not sure what you want to define as the upper & lower bound - seconds or decimals...

Comment: Try: `=INDEX($A$2:$A$600,MATCH(SMALL(INDEX(($C$2:$C$600+$D$2:$D$600)-($F$2+$G$2),),ROW(A1)),INDEX(($C$2:$C$600+$D$2:$D$600)-($F$2+$G$2),),0))` and drag down. This however assumes there are never a duplicate `lat+lon`.

Comment: Hi @JvdV, that one's returning the same site every time I drag it down - don't know why!

Comment: Hi @SolarMike - would it be possible put in the lat-long of the address, then enter a value in miles, and have that generate the co-ordinates of, say, a 60 mile radius? And then write a formula to find all the sites within that radius?

Comment: Works fine for me with some mockup data, can you include a snapshot of your formula?

Comment: Hi @JvdV - edited the post to include a screenshot

Comment: I see, you have lot's of dups. I also stated with that formula it assumes no dups when `lat+lon`. The formula won't work for you unfortunately

Comment: @JvdV I've removed all duplicate values (exact values), but it's still returning the same site each time. How close is too close to count as a duplicate?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised we had some blanks - it works! 
Thank you very much!!